# Associating names with a range of registers, best solution?

Tags: c#, xml, range, cpu-registers

I have a list, which I obtain from an XML file (I am using it as a configuration file) which contains the addresses of registers and the number of subsequent registers to read from each point. My problem is, I need the name of each individual parameter/register to allow me to insert into a similarly named database column, but specifying a range instead of single value elements precludes me from individually associating them with their own name.

At the moment I am considering another XML file from which I could build a list/dictionary to handle this association for me, but this means two config files, an additional list, and perhaps another custom class. Is this too much?

Could anyone offer a better solution? This is my first time working with XML/config so I am unsure what is considered bad practice in this regard. Any help much appreciated, Cheers!

I am using C#.NET 3.5

Comment: You'll have to provide a small example of what your file looks like.

Comment: Of course, apologies, was in quite a rush at the time. Problem solved however :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was a custom object to associate the 'range' parameter I required with the other two 'address' and 'name', this meant listing all required values. In order to retrieve the desired values a base addressed was calculated from this by comparing the range of each address, the results then stored.

Apologies for the vague nature of this question :P